# PhpStorm shows dialog that file I try to edit is not inside my project

Tags: phpstorm

What happened with my Laravel 7 project in PhpStorm 2019.2.3 
that I got an error that file I try to edit is not inside my project:

[image]

But actually path of my project is `/_wwwroot/lar/votes`
with link created with command :

```
ln  -s   /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot  /_wwwroot
```

In my printscreen it is visible that path of the file is shown without link used as

```
/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/...
```

How can it be fixed ?

Comment: As far as I know IDE treats those files (real one and via symlink) as different files (it does not resolve and compare symlinks). Try opening your project (`File | Open` and point to the project root folder) using **real path** (`/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot` as I understand) -- any better now? At the same time: it should work OK as long as you stick to one of the paths and not mixing them up... And for debugging a path mapping can be easily provided.

Comment: Looks like you are right. Are there some options to tune it?  2) Also is there is a way to clear "Open Recent" manually, as usually I open projects with it and now I have 2 links to the same project...

Comment: You can manually remove unwanted project from the Welcome screen (when all projects are closed) or via `File | Open Recent | Manage Projects...` entry at the bottom (will show similar list to what Welcome screen shows). Just hover over and click on `x` on the right. `Del` key should also work.

Comment: No options AFAIK. But check these and related tickets (comments in particular) -- maybe there are some. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85774, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141650